# Proper way to add to org-entities-user

Tags: org-mode

I want to know how to add `\vdots` and `\ddots` to org-entities-user variable. This will display the values when I call org-entities-help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each element of `org-entities-user` is a list of 7 items which according to the manual are:

```
name                 As a string, without the leading backslash.
LaTeX replacement    In ready LaTeX, no further processing will take place.
LaTeX mathp          Either t or nil.  When t this entity needs to be in
                     math mode.
HTML replacement     In ready HTML, no further processing will take place.
                     Usually this will be an &...; entity.
ASCII replacement    Plain ASCII, no extensions.

Latin1 replacement   Use the special characters available in latin1.
utf-8 replacement    Use the special characters available in utf-8.
```

You add new entries like this:

```
(add-to-list 'org-entities-user
             '("vdots" "\\vdots{}" t "&x2999" "..." "..." "⁞"))
```

where the last four entries will vary based on what you want to display in html, ASCII, latin1 and utf8 respectivly.  The `t` in the middle indicates that the `\vdots` Latex macro should be used in math mode.

Comment: This is perfect thanks. Do you know how to look up the HTML replacement?

Comment: I just drew it at shapecatcher.com and copied the hex code of a similar enough unicode character.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ and https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+211D are both two good references.